# Creating a custom html button with background Image and Text

Tags: html

I would like to know how I can create a custom HTML button which has a background Image and I can show a custom text over that image.

For example, I would like to show a submit button for which I have a background image for that button and the text "Submit" comes on top of that Image.

I tried this -

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" style="background-image: url(pages/images/ButtonBackground.png);">
```

However, it does not work properly. I just see the test submit and the button but the image does not show up.

Comment: Check that the image is where it's supposed to be, isn't corrupted and you've set the correct path for it. A tool like Firebug or Chrome's inspector is very useful here.

Comment: I did check.. the image is in the correct position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use a button element with a background. Use e.g. padding properties to make the button suitably large. It is a useful precaution to set a background color for the button, for use when the background image is not shown for some reason, using a color that has sufficient contrast with the text (so it should be similar in color usage to the background image). Example:

```
<button type=submit style="background: #ccc url(test.jpg); padding: 0.5em 1em">Go!</button>
```

Caveat: In old versions of IE, there are several bugs in the implementation of button elements. The bugs bite most seriously if a form has several submit buttons.

The reason for the failure when using an input type=submit element is that they are commonly implemented by browsers using built-in routines that are rather immune to CSS.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend that you use `<button>` instead of `<input type='submit' />` or `<input type='button' />`. The reason is that you can embed HTML elements (nest elements) into the `<button>` element. This way, you can make a much more flexible button, which can be customized even more.

```
<button>
    <span class='image'></span>
    <span class='text'>Click Me!</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" style="background: url(pages/images/ButtonBackground.png) no-repeat; width:px; height:px;">
```

you have to specify the width and height of the image so it covers your button and yes check the path of the image

this is exactly what I have in one of my css and usually what I do in this situation:

html

```
<input type="submit" value="" name="commit" id="message_submit" class="registerbtn"/>
```

css

```
.registerbtn{background:url(../images/btn_registro.jpg) no-repeat; width:98px; height:32px; border:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I created buttons with actual pics on them along with text.  In CSS I put:

```
button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 400px;
 }

#alldogs-close-CSS {
     background-image: url( All_dogs.jpg );
     /*background-size: 100px 130px;*/
     height: 150px;
     width: 300px;
}
```

The button controls my height and width and `#alldogs-close-CSS` is the pic I wanted to show on the button.

In my Index.html page I just put:

```
<button id="alldogs-close-CSS">All Dogs</button>
```

Now the text isn't very pretty at the moment, but I haven't played with it yet. It does work, though.